# " delete reference " in iOS

Tags: ios, reference, distribution, delete-file

I want to make a new "light weight" version from a previous full version which had very large size.

If I delete some unused ".h ", ".m" and .png files by "delete reference" from the previous full version, will those deleted files NOT included in my new "light weighted " distribution .app?

I want customers can download a small size App with files it really needs.
Or must I use "also move to trash" to achieve the effect?

Comment: Don't know, but to check I would do what you said and then review the contents of the .app file. Simply right click on the .app file and use the "Show package contents" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you don't include those in your free target they will not be included with the .ipa. I would recommend mostly removing .png and other large resources since .m and .h files aren't going to save you much download size.

Just make sure to remove them under your Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: thank you all for your prompt reply!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will not be included.

The best way to check is to open up your target's settings and look at the "Build Phases". Under "Compile Sources" and "Copy Bundle Sources" you will see all the code and resources that will be included in your build.

[image: XCode Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This is not how the compiling works, instead check the following:

Go to your project settings, under Build Phases look for copy bundle resources section.

These are the elements that will be copied, if they dont appear here then they wont be copied when compiling (for things like pngs and other heavy files).

And Yes if you delete the reference it will also be deleted from this section.

For .h or .m files, deleting them will almost make no difference and you get the risk of deleting something that could be actually used somewhere which you might have forgotten or are not aware of.